# How do I upload a WCF service to a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a test WCF project. In the same solution I have a C# application that uses that WCF project by simply adding it as a resource and it works well. But how do I upload it (-WCF) to a website?

I tried Build -> Publish. But it didn't give me any dialog; it just said "Publish succeeded". So I converted it to a web application (right click in solution explorer...)
and then published it. Since I wanted to try it – I published it to the file system. But when I now try to add a service reference to it in a C# app – I get the error that "No services were found in the solution". Why is that?

But the question is mainly: when I try to publish it to a website – I don't know what to put as "Service URL" and what as "Site/application".

Here's what I have:

Iservice1:

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string DoWork();
}
```

Service1:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "Hello, world";
    }
}
```

And in the C# app:

```
Service1Client s = new Service1Client();
Text = s.DoWork();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I simply built a web application and added a WCF service to it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to build a `Deployment Package` and then deploying it to IIS either from IIS itself or using `MSDeploy`. You can use the package to deploy your services on any machine you want. Check this [walkthrough](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1081/building-a-web-deploy-package-from-visual-studio-2010/).

Comment: Thanks. I got a web deployment package zip file. What do I do with it now?

Comment: As described in the walkthrough, go to IIS create a new web site, right click on it and select Deploy -> Import Application and import your package. Make sure that before you build your package you have set the correct web site name in the `Web Deployment Package Settings`.

Comment: That will deploy it locally, won't it? I want it on a real website.

Comment: If run it on your local machine, yes. If you have a `Web Server` where you deploy your web applications then upload your package to your web server and run the deployment from there.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, but how do I "run the deployment"? – there seems to be no .exe file there.

Comment: Yes, there is no .exe file. You do this from the IIS or from the [MSDeploy](http://root-project.org/work/net/automated-web-deployment-with-msbuild-and-msdeploy/) command line.